# What do you call an experience where the navigation or menu is the only thing on a homepage?

Tags: interaction-design, navigation, menu, homepage

For example.

[image: The only purpose of this page is to direct users to their desired destination]

This design was used frequently when mobile websites first became a hit. I don't see it as much anymore but I'm considering using it for a web app I'm working on. Just wondering what everyone's thoughts were on this sort of "out-dated" behavior. The reason I'm resorting to this is because there is no specific content area that requires immediate focus.

Comment: All of your pages are exactly equally as likely to be visited?

Comment: Yes, that is the assumption right now. After we look at some analytics, we plan to change it up so that the most visited because the homepage, and we'll have introduce the drop down.

Any ideas as to what this experience is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

Just kidding! In the book Designing interfaces by Jenifer Tidwell (which I highly recommend) she calls this pattern Menu page. I think it's a nice name that both the team and the client understand and could use in a conversation. The pattern only deals with pages which only purpose is to guide people somewhere on the site. It does not deal with how the links is laid out on the canvas.

In the book Mobile Design Pattern Gallery by Theresa Neil your design pattern is called List menu. 
http://mobiledesignpatterngallery.com/mobile-patterns-gallery.php?colid=65438029-72157627607680275&setid=72157627762097550&s=2

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a **gateway** or **portal** since its primary function is just to direct users to a different page.